# Save uploaded images directly under public laravel directory

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image but before doing so, I have to resize the image first that's why I have to user the `ImageIntervention` package. With that, my previous code which is

```
$file->storeAs('uploads', $filename, 'public');
```

will not work the same as before in uploading under public directory. This is the code I have now but my problem is it is uploading to `public\uploads` not in `storage\app\public\uploads`.

```
    $file = $request->file('image-profile');
    $filename = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('U') .'-'. Str::uuid() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    if (!file_exists(storage_path('uploads/'))) { 
        mkdir(storage_path('uploads/'), 666, true);
    }

    $path = storage_path('uploads/' . $filename);

    $img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
    $img->fit(200, 200);
    $img->circle(100, 50, 50, function ($draw) {
    });
    $img->save($path);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify where the public disk should point in config/filesystem.php

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
```

Then run:

```
php artisan storage:link
```